# Replacing socket, only one hot wire, two neutrals from different places

Tags: electrical

[image: socket]

I am replacing a socket because a prong got stuck in it and it was painted over.

When I removed it, I was surprised at what I saw.

The top socket had the red and white wires coming from the left connected to it as you would expect.

However, the bottom socket only was connected to the white neutral from the right.

Am I correct for thinking this is odd? Or is this standard practice?

How do I most safely deal with this situation?

Comment: 2-socket receptacles do have screws for each socket, but those screws are bridged  together using **tabs**.  95% of the time when both screws are used, it's simply as a "wire nut" to connect the two wires to each other (and also to the socket of course).  The way you think it works, only applies if you break the tabs off.

Comment: I interpret @Harper 's comment to mean you could just connect the new receptacle the same way and expect it to be correct, but if you have the time you could find out where the wires are coming from and where they are going before installing the new receptacle. How many cables are in the box? Is there just the one 12/3 + gnd (B, R, W, gnd) and another 12/2 + gnd (B, W, gnd)?  Were the two blacks wire nutted together? Presumably the R and the B in the 12/3 cable are on different breakers? common trip 2-pole breaker? Are they on different legs so there is 240 V across the B and the R?

Comment: I am supposing that the 12/2 cable goes to another receptacle and so there is a common neutral for two breakers. If this is correct, the two breakers must be on different legs (240 V difference between B and R). And the two breakers must have a physical link on their manual switches (but would not necessarily be common trip?).

Comment: Was there a tab or fin on the silver-screw side of the old receptacle, or was it broken off?

Comment: None of the tabs were broken off. The wires are 14 gauge, this is a 14 amp circuit.

Comment: Sorry 15 amps *

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Harper's comment on my question, and his comment on a deleted answer, I came up with a solution.

Both to play it safe (i don't know why, but I don't like the idea of using a socket as a wire nut) and because I did not have enough length left on the original hotwire, I went with the following:

I tied the two original neutrals as well as a new neutral together with a wire nut. The new neutral goes to the top neutral side of the socket.

I tied a new hot wire to the original with a wire nut, running the new hotwire to the bottom hot side of the socket.

No tabs broken on the socket.

This seems to work fine.

Comment: Presumably you shut off the breakers when you worked on this. Would you describe what breaker or breakers control the black and the red hots?

Comment: So do you have *two* hot wires going to the receptacle--one on the bottom and one  on the top? This the red hot, right? The black hot is not connected to this receptacle, right?

Comment: Yes the breakers were off.

Comment: No, did not touch the black wires. Just extended the red wire that was already going to the socket

Comment: What type of breakers on the red and the black? Were they separate breakers or were they in a 2-pole breaker with a physical link on the handles?

Comment: If you have everything put back together and want to measure the voltage difference between the red and the black, you'd plug an extension cord into the receptacle the black feeds and bring the female end of the cord near to the receptacle fed by the red hot. Put one probe of a voltmeter into the hot slot of the receptacle and the other probe into the hot on the extension cord. You'd get either 0 or 240 V, and the latter is what you'd want. If you got 0 V you could be overloading the shared neutral.

Comment: Thanks Jim! I am not sure exactly what breakers thrse go to (I just turned all of them off when I was working), but my guess would be a standard single pole 15 amp.

Comment: Jim, what if they are on the same circuit? Would that still hold true?

Comment: If you have two always hots, B and R, then I don't expect they would be on the same circuit, but my experience is limited. If this is all coming from one single pole breaker, I don't know why you would have a red and a black always hot.  If this were on a single 1-pole breaker, there would be 0 V between R and B. There would also be 0 V between R and B if there were two breakers on the same leg. I have gotten confused about this whole case. If it is now back together and working, you'd have to do some investigation.

Comment: So Jim, what I am deducing from your comment is, in home wiring, red corresponds to the "back stroke (-120v)" and black corresponds to the "forward stroke (+120v)"?

Comment: That is one way to describe the situation you have. If so, there will be two breakers. The red wire in a cable with R, B, W, gnd can be used to carry one leg and the black the other in something called a multiwire branch circuit (MWBC), which it may be here, but R can also be used in other ways.  I'm not really up on this, but in all the ways R is used it is an "ungrounded conductor" meaning it is carrying current and it is an always hot or is a switched hot.